# Informatica : Count the number of rows based on sequence of number

Tags: informatica

I have table where source has 1 column, like below. for example, column name is A and I have set of records in the source.

```
A
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

I want to populate two columns in target, Say columns are A and B.

Column A in the Target has same values as in source and column B has count

```
A B
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
3 1
```

Can someone please explain how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If source is a dbms like oracle, you can use source qualifier overwrite sql like below. Use row number and partition by to generate sequence for every A.

```
Select
A, row_number() over(partition by A order by A) as B
From mytable
```

If you're looking for infomatica only solution then this is how you can do it.

1. Sort the data by column A
2. Use ex transformation, create one in/out two var, and one out port.
   We are going to compare first val with prev val, if they r same, add 1to the sequence else start from 1 again.

```
A in/out 
v_B = iif (A=prev_A, v_B +1, 1)
prev_A=A
o_B =v_B
```

3. Link A and o_B to the target.